# Issue with difference between Delphi XE4 and XE7 JSON marshalling of TPointF type

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe4, delphi-xe7

I am in the process of upgrading a project that was originally coded with Delphi XE4 using the new XE7 version. This application saves its main output as a marshaled JSON file that the users load, edit, save similar to what would be done with a Word document.

They do not work directly with the json, it is just used as the file format. The issue I am having is XE7 outputs the type `TPointF` differently than XE4 which causes an issue when trying to unmarshall.

This would not be an issue if I only had to handle opening files created with the new version but I have to support the old version files for at least a year. It looks like XE7 outputs all the possible fields in TPointF record (it is a variant record type)

Below is an example of the **XE7 output**

Using `TJsonValue` and `TJsonMarshal`:

```json
{
  "type":"tstMnfHole.TmnfHole",
  "id":1,
  "fields":
  {
    "fctrPoint":
    [
      [0.625,132.5],
      0.625,
      132.5
    ]
  }
}
```

Using `rest.json` `TJson.ObjectToJsonString(myHole)`

```json
{
  "ctrPoint":
  [
    [0.625,132.5],
    0.625,
    132.5
  ]
}
```

Below is an example of the **XE4 output**

Using `TJsonValue` and `TJsonMarshal`:

```json
{
  "type":"tstMnfHole.TmnfHole",
  "id":1,
  "fields":
  {
    "fctrPoint":[0.625,132.5]
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a simple way to handle this with out having to override the default marshalling and create a custom converter/reverter so that the XE7 version outputs the same as XE4?
2. Is this worth posting on Embarcadero Quality Central?

small console test app for both XE4 and XE7.

---

XE7

---

```
program testPointf;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Types,
  // rest.json,
  data.dbxjsonReflect,
  //data.dbxjson,
  system.json,
  tstMnfHole in 'tstMnfHole.pas';

var
  myHole:  TmnfHole;
  valJson: TJSONValue;
  Marshal: TJSONMarshal;
begin
  try
    {*** Create new test hole ***}
    myHole      := TmnfHole.Create(0.625, 132.5);
    try
      Marshal   := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);
      try
        valJson := Marshal.Marshal(myHole);
        try
          Writeln(valJson.ToString);
        finally
          valJson.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Marshal.Free;
      end;
    finally
      myHole.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

---

```
unit tstMnfHole;

interface

uses system.types;

type
  TmnfHole = class(TObject)
    //...
    fctrPoint:  TPointF;
    constructor create; overload;
    constructor create(thisCtrPoint: TPointF); overload;
    constructor create(thisX, thisY: single); overload;
    //...
  end;

implementation

{ TmnfHole }
constructor TmnfHole.create;
begin
  fctrPoint := TPointF.Create(0.75, 120.50);
end;

constructor TmnfHole.create(thisCtrPoint: TPointF);
begin
  fctrPoint := TPointF.Create(thisCtrPoint.X, thisCtrPoint.Y);
end;

constructor TmnfHole.create(thisX, thisY: single);
begin
  fctrPoint := TPointF.Create(thisX, thisY);
end;

end.
```

---

---

XE4

---

testPointf.dpr: replace `system.json` with `data.dbxjson`

Comment: Looking at how the implementation of `System.Types.TPointF` changed so drastically from XE4 ([record](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Types.TPointF)) to XE5 ([variant record](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Types.TPointF)), I dare to say that the true reason for the difference is rather `TPointF` itself than the JSON serialization mechanism.

Comment: I had not looked at that yet.  That would do it. Thank you for the heads up.  Based on that, there really isn't much I can do but deal with the difference some how.  Or maybe use a recordhelper, adapter or something similar. It really makes me wonder if it is a good idea to use the marshaling the way I am right now.  I may have to go back to using RTTI for the serialization for each of the classes so that when cases like that come up they can be handled with some logic.  Bummer.  It was nice to be able to use the same code for the entire hierarchy.

Comment: I believe that a sudden change in RTL types are not to be expected, this is more Embarcaderos fault than yours. I've just done a quick test and writing a `TmnfHoleLegacy` class that wraps `TPointFType` instead of `TPointF` works great as an alternative when de-serializing fails. Are you still interested in that as an answer?

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar: That's a pretty good idea. Have you done so? If yes, do you have a link for people to vote on? If not, would you like someone else to do it?

Comment: Gunther: Sorry got tied up yesterday, I am still interested and would be willing to vote on

Comment: Issue is reported as https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9757

Comment: Thank you very much. I also want to thank Sir Rufo for fixing my formatting issues with the original question.